# Using the TFS Api, how can I retrieve a list of all the testers to whom test cases can be assigned to in a given plan?

Tags: tfs

Using the TFS Api, I am trying to get a list of all the testers for a given project.

The same list of testers appear in MTM when allocating the assigned-to field.

How can I get this list programmatically?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a request for others to write code instead of a question about a specific problem with existing code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by using TFS identities, which is the same thing you will find in MTM.

Firstly get a list of all the allowed users like this:

```
var allowedItems = workItemStore.FieldDefinitions[CoreField.AssignedTo].AllowedValues;
```

Now I've created a dict object which I will use as the binding source for a combobox:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<TeamFoundationIdentity, string>();
```

Now I populate that dict object:

```
foreach (var allowedUser in allowedItems)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (allowedUser.ToString() != "Administrator")
                    {
                        TeamFoundationIdentity userInfo = ims.ReadIdentity(IdentitySearchFactor.DisplayName,
                            allowedUser.ToString(), MembershipQuery.Direct, ReadIdentityOptions.None);
                        dict.Add(userInfo, allowedUser.ToString());
                    }

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //error handling here
                }

            }
```

Next (optional) I bind the dict as datasource:

```
 comboBoxWinTester.DataSource = new BindingSource(dict, null);
            comboBoxWinTester.DisplayMember = "Value";
            comboBoxWinTester.ValueMember = "Key";
```

Notice now I can assign test points using code like this, where identity = teamFoundationIdentity:

```
foreach (var tp in test.PointAssignments)
 {
     tp.AssignedTo = identity;
     suite.AssignTestPoints(test.PointAssignments);
}
```